# sfdx Sharing Settings scratch orgs

Tags: case, sharing, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

We use in our org case sharing (**Setup-->Security Controls-->Sharing Settings-->Case** (**Default Internal Access** From **Public Read/Write/Transfer** to **Private**))

Wa want this sharing settings in place when we create our scratch orgs, Is there a way to achieve that by sfdx cli command or some config in the project-scratch-def.json file?

After some searches, i have locate the information by SOQL:

```
Organization o = [Select DefaultCaseAccess from Organization];
```

But i can't update it by apex code for example

```
o.DefaultCaseAccess = 'None';
```

The field is not writable:

```
Field is not writeable: Organization.DefaultCaseAccess
```

Thank you for your help;

Answer (score 4):

Probably a bit late but better than never.

You can use **sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d data/standard-object-stub/ -w 1 -u $SCRATCH_ORG_ALIAS** with a **package.xml** that references a **Case.object** file with the following content in a **objects** subfolder before you deploy your sources

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <sharingModel>Read</sharingModel>
</CustomObject>
```

This will only change the sharing setting, which will take some time so you might want to delay the further steps like package installation or source push a bit.

**Update 12/2019:**

Within the topic of unlocked packaged (that might have managed packages with certain OWD sharing settings as a dependency) I've come across a probably interesting known issue in this field:

[success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SGtdQAG](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SGtdQAG)

That known issue raises hopes on better support for changing OWD sharing settings based on scratch org definition files.

**Update 09/2020:**

Actually that got improved recently, you can use the scratch org definition file:

```
{
  "orgName": "Scratch Org",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "language":"en_US",
  "features": [
    "AuthorApex",
    "ContactsToMultipleAccounts",
    "StateAndCountryPicklist"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "accountSettings": {
      "enableAccountTeams": true
    }
  },
  "objectSettings": {
    "opportunity": {
      "sharingModel": "private"
    },
    "account": {
      "sharingModel": "read"
    },
    "case": {
      "sharingModel": "read"
    },
    "contact": {
      "sharingModel": "private"
    }
  }
}
```