# Package version creation results in field integrity exception (Case access level below organization default)

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, sharing-rule, scratch-org-definition-file

I am trying to create a package version.

My dev hub has the following for case:

[image]

Running a query under dev console gives me:

[image]

When I try to create a package version, I get :

```
Practice_Assignment_Team: field integrity exception: unknown (Case access level below organization default)
```

When I look at that role (Practice_Assignment_Team)  I see:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Role xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <caseAccessLevel>None</caseAccessLevel>
    <contactAccessLevel>Edit</contactAccessLevel>
    <mayForecastManagerShare>false</mayForecastManagerShare>
    <name>Practice Assignment Team</name>
    <opportunityAccessLevel>Edit</opportunityAccessLevel>
    <parentRole>Super_User</parentRole>
</Role>
```

In my project scratch def I have:

```
{
  "orgName": "Demo company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["EnableSetPasswordInApi", "SharedActivities"],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    }
  },
  "objectSettings": {
    "case": {
      "sharingModel": "read"
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to proceed. I saw [sfdx Sharing Settings scratch orgs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218183/sfdx-sharing-settings-scratch-orgs) but that seems to be a different issue. Any guidance please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't set the `<caseAccessLevel/>` lower than the OWD, so I would set it to `Edit` in the Role .xml file